# Adding grid view values to a list VB

Tags: vb.net, gridview, for-loop

I have an excel sheet that imports to grid view fine

then i start looping through the columns in grid view but it skips over a few values. It seems to only skip ones that are only numbers.

```
 Dim column As New List(Of Object)

 For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
            column.Add(DataGridView1(i, 0).Value)
            i = i + 1
 Next
```

Ideas?

Comment: `i=i+1` will cause your code to only add every *other* column.  It will skip all evenly-indexed columns.

Comment: `Next` already means `i=i+1` in VB. it's same as `Next i`.